# Why vba is replacing SN-Sh as zeros in the Word Snapshot as 00ap00ot?

Tags: excel, vba

When I am trying to add new sheets with today's "mm-dd snapshot"
the letters sn-sh are replaced by 00 like "00ap00ot"

```
Sub SheetNameAsCurrentDate()
Dim SheetName As String
    'I am trying to add a new sheet with date & name
     SheetName = Format(Date, "mm-dd snapshot")
     Sheets. Add, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sheet name should be:

```
SheetName = Format(Date, "mm-dd") & " snapshot"
```

You are formatting a `Date`, which has a time associated... use of "s", etc., are related to seconds, etc.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the zeroes, because `s`,`n`& `h` are [special letters in Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications). If you like to define the format additionally, this is a way to do it:

```
Sub SheetNameAsCurrentDate()

    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = Format(Date, "mm-dd ""snapshot""")
    Debug.Print sheetName

End Sub
```